# File MIME type as argument. - Views

Tags: files, views

I am trying to create a view, listing nodes with a specific file type.
This can be achieved using filters. But I want to do it using views argument.
Say the view page's pathe should be 'myurl.com/post/attachment/**text/plain**' where 'text/plain' is MIME type of the file, and should list all the nodes having txt file in file field.

How to do that?

Here are the setting of the view...

```
 Path: /post/attachment/%
```

**Relationships**

```
File Usage: File
```

**Contextual filters**

```
When the filter value is NOT in the URL
Provide default value
Fixed value 
arg(2)
```